# Combine rows from Mulitple tables into single table

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-administration

I have one parent table Products with multiple child tables -Hoses,Steeltubes,ElectricCables,FiberOptics.

ProductId -Primary key field in Product table
ProductId- ForeignKey field in Hoses,Steeltubes,ElectricCables,FiberOptics.

Product table has 1 to many relationship with Child tables

I want to combine result of all tables .
For eg - Product P1 has PK field ProductId which is used in all child tables as FK.

If Hoses table has 4 record with ProductId 50 and Steeltubes table has 2 records with ProductId 50 when I perform left join then left join is doing cartesian product of records showing 8 record as result But it should be 4 records .

```
               ;with HOSESTEELCTE
       as
      (
  select  '' as ModeType, '' as FiberOpticQty , '' as NumberFibers,  '' as    FiberLength,  '' as CableType ,  '' as Conductorsize , '' as Voltage,'' as   ElecticCableLength , s.TubeMaterial , s.TubeQty, s.TubeID , s.WallThickness ,  s.DWP ,s.Length as SteelLength , h.HoseSeries, h.HoseLength ,h.ProductId  
  from Hoses h
   left join
   (
   --'' as HoseSeries,'' as HoseLength ,
  select  TubeMaterial , TubeQty,  TubeID , WallThickness ,  DWP ,        Length,ProductId  from SteelTubes 
   ) s on (s.ProductId = h.ProductId)  

  ) select * from HOSESTEELCTE
```

Comment: MySQL tag removed because it doesn't have CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no relationships between child tables and you simply want a list of all child entities which make up a product you could generate a cte which has a number of rows which are equal to the largest number of entries across all the child tables for a product. In the example below I have used a dates table to simplify the example.
so for this data

```
create table products(pid int);  
insert into products values
(1),(2);
create table hoses (pid int,descr varchar(2));
insert into hoses values (1,'h1'),(1,'h2'),(1,'h3'),(1,'h4');
create table steeltubes (pid int,descr varchar(2));
insert into steeltubes values (1,'t1'),(1,'t2');
create table electriccables(pid int,descr varchar(2));
truncate table electriccables
insert into electriccables values (1,'e1'),(1,'e2'),(1,'e3'),(2,'e1');
```

this cte

```
    ;with cte as
    (select row_number() over(partition by p.pid order by datekey) rn, p.pid
    from dimdate, products p
    where datekey  < 20050105)

select * from cte
```

create a cartesian join (one of the rare ocassions where an implicit join helps) pid to rn
result

```
rn                   pid
-------------------- -----------
                   1           1
                   2           1
                   3           1
                   4           1
                   1           2
                   2           2
                   3           2
                   4           2
```

And if we add the child tables

```
;with cte as
(select row_number() over(partition by p.pid order by datekey) rn, p.pid
from dimdate, products p
where datekey  < 20050106)
select c.pid,h.descr hoses,s.descr steeltubes,e.descr electriccables from cte c
left join (select h.*, row_number() over(order by h.pid) rn from hoses h) h on h.rn = c.rn and h.pid = c.pid
left join (select s.*, row_number() over(order by s.pid) rn from steeltubes s) s on s.rn = c.rn and s.pid = c.pid
left join (select e.*, row_number() over(order by e.pid) rn from electriccables e) e on e.rn = c.rn and e.pid = c.pid
where h.rn is not null or s.rn is not null or e.rn is not null
order by c.pid,c.rn
```

we get this

```
pid         hoses steeltubes electriccables
----------- ----- ---------- --------------
          1 h1    t1         e1
          1 h2    t2         e2
          1 h3    NULL       e3
          1 h4    NULL       NULL
          2 NULL  NULL       e1
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the result having 8 rows can be expected to be the result, since your four records are joined with the first record in the other table and then your four records are joined with the second record of the other table, making it 4 + 4 = 8.

The very fact that you expect 4 records to be in the result instead of 8 shows that you want to use some kind of grouping. You can group your inner query issued for SteelTubes by ProductId, but then you will need to use aggregate functions for the other columns. Since you have only explained the structure of the desired output, but not the semantics, I am not able with my current knowledge about your problem to determine what aggregations you need.

Once you find out the answer for the first table, you will be able to easily add the other tables into the selection as well, but in case of large data you might get some scaling problems, so you might want to have a table where you store these groups, maintain it when something changes and use it for these selections.